# Responsive Design - different font-size galaxy

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i have a question. i have a div, in this div there is one more div with a text "Benjamin". The font-size is 7vh. when i check the site on galaxy s4 mini the text has the right Position and size. when i check the site with galaxy a5 the text is on the wrong Position. I check the site with IPhone 4 and 5. It's always correct. Only galaxy a5 Show me the wrong. We use the same Version of Chrome.

http://www.benwillgruber.com/stefanseite/test/index.php --> The site
http://www.benwillgruber.com/stefanseite/test/wrong_galaxy_a5.jpg--> wrong Position
http://www.benwillgruber.com/stefanseite/test/google_nexus_10_emulator.png --> right one
http://www.benwillgruber.com/stefanseite/test/galaxy_s4_mini.png --> right one.

CSS:

```
 * { box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
    background-color: #3C3C3B; /* Dunkel Grau */
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;

}

/* Willkommenseite */
#startseite {
    width: 100vm;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#spalte1reihe1 {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 22vh;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ECECEC; /* Grau */
}

#spalte2reihe1 {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 22vh;   
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#spalte3reihe1 {
    width: 25vw;
    float: left;
    height: 22vh;
    background-color: #ECECEC; /* Grau */
}

/* Willkommenseite Benjamin Willgruber */

#spalte1reihe2 {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 16vh;
    float: left;
    background-color: #2DAB66; /* Grün */
}

#spalte2reihe2 {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 16vh;   
    float: left;
    background-color: #3C3C3B;
}

#spalte3reihe2 {
    width: 25vw;
    float: left;
    height: 16vh;
    background-color: #2DAB66; /* Grün */
}

/* Willkommenseite kombiniert mit */

#spalte1reihe3 {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 17vh;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ECECEC; /* Grau */
}

#spalte2reihe3 {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 17vh;   
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#spalte3reihe3 {
    width: 25vw;
    float: left;
    height: 17vh;
    background-color: #ECECEC; /* Grau */
}

/* Willkommenseite Gumhalter Stefan */

#spalte1reihe4 {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 16vh;
    float: left;
    background-color: #1E788B; /* Blau */
}

#spalte2reihe4 {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 16vh;   
    float: left;
    background-color: #3C3C3B;
}

#spalte3reihe4 {
    width: 25vw;
    float: left;
    height: 16vh;
    background-color: #1E788B; /* Blau */
}

#spalte1reihe5 {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 29vh;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ECECEC; /* Grau */
}

#spalte2reihe5 {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 29vh;   
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#spalte3reihe5 {
    width: 25vw;
    float: left;
    height: 29vh;
    background-color: #ECECEC; /* Grau */
}

#benjaminwillgruber {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 16vh;
    padding-left: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

#grafikmediendesign {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 16vh;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;

}

#benjamin {
    font-size: 7vh;
    color: #ffffff;

}

#willgruber {
    font-size: 7vh;
    color: #ffffff;

}

#grafik {
    font-size: 7vh;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#mediendesign {
    font-size: 7vh;
    color: #ffffff;

}

/* Auflösung 300 bis 500 */
/* Seitliche Balken werden ausgeblendet */


@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1000px) 
{

    #spalte1reihe1 {
        display: none;
    }
    #spalte2reihe1 {
        width: 100vw;
    }
    #spalte3reihe1 {
        display: none;
    }
    #spalte1reihe2 {
        display: none;
    }
    #spalte2reihe2 {
        width: 100vw;
    }
    #spalte3reihe2 {
        display: none;
    }
    #spalte1reihe3 {
        display: none;
    }
    #spalte2reihe3 {
        width: 100vw;
    }
    #spalte3reihe3 {
        display: none;
    }
    #spalte1reihe4 {
        display: none;
    }
    #spalte2reihe4 {
        width: 100vw;
    }
    #spalte3reihe4 {
        display: none;
    }
    #spalte1reihe5 {
        display: none;
    }
    #spalte2reihe5 {
        width: 100vw;
    }
    #spalte3reihe5 {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "de">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./css/style.css">

        <style type = "text/css">
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'avril';
                src: url('./font/arvil_sans-webfont.eot');
                src: url('./font/arvil_sans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                     url('./font/arvil_sans-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
                     url('./font/arvil_sans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
                     url('./font/arvil_sans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
                     url('./font/arvil_sans-webfont.svg#arvil_sans-webfont') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;

            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'sensation';
                src: url('./font/sansation_regular-webfont.eot');
                src: url('./font/sansation_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                     url('./font/sansation_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
                     url('./font/sansation_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
                     url('./font/sansation_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
                     url('./font/sansation_regular-webfont.svg#sansation_regular-webfont') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;

            }           
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = 'startseite'>
            <div id = "reihe1">
                <div id = "spalte1reihe1">
                </div>
                <div id = "spalte2reihe1">
                </div>
                <div id = "spalte3reihe1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id = "reihe2">
                <div id = "spalte1reihe2">
                </div>
                <div id = "spalte2reihe2">
                    <div id = 'benjaminwillgruber'>
                        <div id = 'benjamin'>
                            <font style = "font-family: 'avril'">Benjamin</font>
                        </div>
                        <div id = 'willgruber'>
                            <font style = "font-family: 'avril'">Willgruber</font>
                        </div>                  
                    </div>
                    <div id = 'grafikmediendesign'>
                        <div id = 'grafik'>
                            <font style = "font-family: 'avril'">Grafik</font>
                        </div>
                        <div id = 'mediendesign'>
                            <font style = "font-family: 'avril'">Mediendesign</font>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id = "spalte3reihe2">
                </div>
        <div id = "reihe3">
            <div id = "spalte1reihe3">
            </div>
            <div id = "spalte2reihe3">
            </div>
            <div id = "spalte3reihe3">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id = "reihe4">
            <div id = "spalte1reihe4">
            </div>
            <div id = "spalte2reihe4">
            </div>
            <div id = "spalte3reihe4">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id = "reihe5">
            <div id = "spalte1reihe5">
            </div>
            <div id = "spalte2reihe5">
            </div>
            <div id = "spalte3reihe5">
            </div>
        </div>
             </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of Android on A5 and which browser?

Comment: Android 5.02 and Chrome 46.0.2490.76 --> Galaxy a5; Android 4.4.2 and Chrome 46.0.2490.76 --> Galaxy s4 mini

Answer (score 0):

Because I can't comment...  The text is not aligning properly on a standard page (i'm assuming this is meant to be for mobile only?)

I'm assuming the screen sizes are different from the A5 and the s4.  You will likely have to use media queries to ensure that the text displays properly based on the screen sizes available.   Is the CSS that you posted the entirety of your css code?

(Again... I wanted to post this as a comment, but I don't have the rep.   I'm willing to help, just need more information.

Comment: i thought, i can Change the font-size with vh or vw. so it doesn't matter which Screen size do i have. the site should be for deskopt, Notebook and mobile phone. and know the screensize is different, but i thougt vh or vw will Change to the right size. it works on Desktop pc, Notebook, only mobile phone the font-size doesn't work

Comment: And do you know a better way to test a Website for responsive design? do you know a Website?

Answer (score 0):

THE SOLUTION OF MY PROBLEM WAS: i forgot to set line-height. now it works for the other devices.